What does "This job" mean?
In fantasy movie Poor Things (2023), Doctor Baxter, who has a deformed face, and his student Max walk down a street:

MAX: Have you ever thought of growing a beard sir?
BAXTER: I look like a big dog in a cravat.
MAX: Kids like dogs. This job.
BAXTER: Yes. Come.

They arrive at Baxter’s house.
What does "This job" mean ?

Without more context, it means nothing.

@suchiuomizu - I believe OP expects whoever answers this question to already be aware of the context.

It's a reference to Dr. Baxter offering him a position in the scene before. It's a little easier to see the chain of events in the script.

BAXTER: I need someone. An assistant on a project.
MAX: I would -

You could rewrite the line thusly.

MAX: Kids like dogs. [Please tell me more about] this job [that you just mentioned, that I am clearly very interested in].
BAXTER Yes. Come [this way and I'll tell you about it]

